# Cancate three channels to one

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have separated the RGB channels from Image to perform individual operations on one.
Now I need to add them together. Please Suggest something.

Comment: Show some sample data that you need to concat with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a copy of the original image and then replace the channels of the copy with your RGB produced.

For Example:

```
img_cpy =img.copy()
img_cpy[:,:,0]=r
img_cpy[:,:,1]=g
img_cpy[:,:,2]=b
```

Make sure the shapes do match.

Answer (score 1):

Another way in Python/OpenCV is to use cv2.merge().

```
color = cv2.merge([b,g,r])
```